# Problems with appending data to FormData in Angular Net 5 Application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am developing a angular 11 and net 5 application and trying to implement the file upload functionality. In the end, it turns out I am able to send picture to the server, but am not able to send value of some of my other properties. Here is my code, I will try to shorten as much as I can, feel free to let me know if I am missing some relevant parts:

**Model:**

```
public class Office : BaseEntity
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }

    public int? HospitalId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HospitalId")]
    public Hospital Hospitals { get; set; }
    
    public decimal InitialExaminationFee { get; set; }
    public decimal FollowUpExaminationFee { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MedicalRecord> MedicalRecords { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost("pictureattempt")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateOffice1([FromForm] 
   OfficeCreateEditDto officeDto)
    {
        var userId = User.GetUserId();

        var doctor = await _doctorRepository.FindDoctorByUserId(userId);

        var office = _mapper.Map<Office>(officeDto);

        office.DoctorId = doctor.Id;

        if (officeDto.Picture != null)
        {
            office.Picture = await _fileStorageService.SaveFile(container, officeDto.Picture);
        }

        await _officeRepository.CreateOffice(office);
       
        return NoContent();
    }
```

**DTO:**

```
public class OfficeCreateEditDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? HospitalId { get; set; }
    public decimal InitialExaminationFee { get; set; }
    public decimal FollowUpExaminationFee { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Range(-90, 90)]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [Range(-180, 180)]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Picture { get; set; }

}
```

**service:**

```
createOffice1(office: OfficeCreateEdit1) {
const formData = this.BuildFormData(office);
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'offices/pictureattempt', 
formData); }

private BuildFormData(office: OfficeCreateEdit1): FormData {
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('initialExaminationFee', 
JSON.stringify(office.initialExaminationFee));
formData.append('followUpExaminationFee', 
JSON.stringify(office.followUpExaminationFee));
formData.append('hospitalId', JSON.stringify(office.hospitalId));

if (office.street){
formData.append('street', office.street);
}
if (office.city){
formData.append('city', office.city);
}
if (office.country){
formData.append('country', office.country);
}
if (office.description){
formData.append('description', office.description);
}

if (office.picture){
  formData.append('picture', office.picture);
}

if (office.latitude) {
formData.append('latitude', JSON.stringify(office.latitude));
}
if (office.longitude) {
formData.append('longitude', JSON.stringify(office.longitude));
}
return formData;
}
```

**model.ts:**

```
export interface OfficeCreateEdit1 {
id: number;
initialExaminationFee: number;
followUpExaminationFee: number;
street: string;
city: string;
country: string;
description: string;
latitude: number;
longitude: number;
hospitalId: number;
picture: File;
```

}

**component.ts:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-add-office-doctor1',
templateUrl: './add-office-doctor1.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-office-doctor1.component.css']})
export class AddOfficeDoctor1Component implements OnInit {
officeForm: FormGroup;
hospitalList = [];
initialCoordinates: CoordinatesMap[] = [];
model: Office;
```

constructor(public officesService: OfficesService,
private router: Router,
private fb: FormBuilder) { }

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.officesService.getHospitals()
.subscribe(res => this.hospitalList = res as []);

this.createOfficeForm();
}

createOfficeForm() {
this.officeForm = this.fb.group({
  street: ['', [Validators.required]],
  city: ['', [Validators.required]],
  country: ['', [Validators.required]],
  initialExaminationFee: ['', [Validators.required]],
  followUpExaminationFee: ['', [Validators.required]],
  description: ['', [Validators.required]],
  longitude: ['', [Validators.required]],
  latitude: ['', [Validators.required]],
  hospitalId: [null],
  picture: ''
 });
 }

onSubmit() {
if (this.officeForm.get('hospitalId') === undefined) {
  this.officeForm.get('hospitalId').setValue(null);
}
this.officesService.createOffice1(this.officeForm.value).subscribe(() => {
  this.resetForm(this.officeForm);
  this.router.navigateByUrl('offices/officeslistdoctor');
},
error => {
  console.log(error);
});}

resetForm(form: FormGroup) {
form.reset();
this.officesService.formData = new OfficeCreateEdit();}

onImageSelected(image){
this.officeForm.get('picture').setValue(image);
}

onSelectedLocation(coordinates: CoordinatesMap) {
this.officeForm.patchValue(coordinates);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
  <div class="col-4">
    <form
      [formGroup]="officeForm"
      (ngSubmit)="officeForm.valid && onSubmit()"
    >
      <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Add Office</h2>
      <hr />
      <app-text-input
        [formControl]="officeForm.controls['street']"
        [label]="'Street'"
      ></app-text-input>
      <app-text-input
        [formControl]="officeForm.controls['city']"
        [label]="'City'"
      ></app-text-input>
      <app-text-input
        [formControl]="officeForm.controls['country']"
        [label]="'Country'"
      ></app-text-input>
      <app-text-input
        [formControl]="officeForm.controls['initialExaminationFee']"
        [label]="'Initial Examination Fee'"
      ></app-text-input>
      <app-text-input
        [formControl]="officeForm.controls['followUpExaminationFee']"
        [label]="'Follow Up Examination Fee'"
      ></app-text-input>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="hospitalId">
            <option value="null">--Select Hospital if any--</option>
            <option
              *ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList"
              value="{{ hospital.id }}"
            >
              {{ hospital.hospitalName }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea
            type="text"
            placeholder="Description"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="description"
            rows="10"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <span
          style="font-size: 14px"
          class="text-danger ml-3"
          *ngIf="
            officeForm.get('description').invalid &&
            officeForm.get('description').touched &&
            officeForm.get('description').errors['required']
          "
        >
          Please enter a Description
        </span>
      </div>

      <app-img-input
      [urlCurrentImage]="model?.picture"
      (onImageSelected)="onImageSelected($event)"> 
      </app-img-input>

      <label style="font-size: small"
        ><strong>Select Location:</strong></label
      >
      <div class="mb-15" style="position: relative; width: 745px">
        <app-map (selectedLocation)="onSelectedLocation($event)"></app-map>
      </div>
      <div
        style="margin-top: 530px; margin-bottom: 40px"
        class="form-group text-center"
      >
        <button
          [disabled]="!officeForm.valid"
          class="btn btn-success mr-2"
          type="submit"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Everything works if I do not pass to the server hospitalid, initial and followupexaminationfee, but if I do that, I get the message (for example for followupfee): **The value '"777"' is not valid for FollowUpExaminationFee."**. I dont know how to solve this, spent like half a day trying to figure out, so any help is more then welcomed.

Comment: Could you pls check which line burst out the error? I mean that did you check if the data can be received in your backend program when you send the request with hospitalid. And if the data can be received successfully, then the issue toke place in `.SaveFile`?

Comment: I found the solution upon so much stress...the problem is in typebinder, it does not recognize decimal and int, so I will post my answer here in case someone else encounters the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, the problem is in typebinder, so I added a new class:

```
 public class TypeBinder<T> : IModelBinder
 {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var propertyName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyName);
        
        if (value == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var deserializedValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> 
 (value.FirstValue);
                bindingContext.Result = 
 ModelBindingResult.Success(deserializedValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(propertyName, "The 
 given value is not of the correct type");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I added in my dto:

```
     public class OfficeCreateEditDto
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(TypeBinder<int?>))]
    public int? HospitalId { get; set; }


    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(TypeBinder<decimal>))]
    public decimal InitialExaminationFee { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(TypeBinder<decimal>))]
    public decimal FollowUpExaminationFee { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Range(-90, 90)]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [Range(-180, 180)]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Picture { get; set; }
    }
```